# Android: LinearLayout with match_parent doesn't Match Parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/filters_view_container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#ededed"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingLeft="20dp"
  android:paddingRight="20dp" >

   <ExpandableListView
       android:id="@+id/filters_List"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:divider="#00000000">
   </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout has a gray background. I want this background to fill the whole screen (the space between the blue bar and the black bar), so I set the height of the LinearLayout to match_parent, but it keeps wrapping the list that contents, so I get a white gap. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Anybody could give me a hint about how to make this?

Thanks!

EDIT: petrumo and Tanis.7x were almost right. Some parent views wasn't taking all the available space. I fixed it, and now all the parent views are taking all the space. The first view that isn't filling the space is the LinearLayout I posted (with ID `filters_view_container`). It has `android:layout_height="match_parent"` so I don't understand why is not taking all the space.

I am adding a snapshot of the hierarchy viewer with this LinearLayout selected.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked DDMS' hierarchy viewer to make sure that it indeed is not matching the parent? It looks like the ListView should be taking up that extra space, so a footer view or overscroll footer color might be taking up the remaining space (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7623153/1253844).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is one level higher, the previous View is not taking the entire space. If you post more layout code I can give more hints.

Comment: Almost. I took a look at the hierarchy viewer and some parent views wasn't taking all the available space. I fixed that, but linearLayout isn't taking all the space despite it has height:match_parent. I edited the question.

Comment: Try to figure out where the chain of views stops taking the full view and fix it as well, or if the LinearList is the last one, try with fill_parent or to move the bg one level higher.

Comment: Thanks, I've moved the background to the next upper level and now it shows as I wanted. I am still confused about why the linearLayout is not taking all the space, so if somebody has any ideas, please, share it with the classroom.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt post your edit text xml; anyways the listview IS filling/matching the parent, but your root view specified left and right padding of 20dp.  So it filled the root layout where the root layout has left 20dp and right 20dp