# Android adMob inside a webview - layout issue

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, uiwebview, admob

I'm currently trying to put an ad using adMob at the bottom of the webview, but so far the webview is taking over the whole screen. I essentially just want a little banner at the bottom and the webview on top

here is what I have:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/footer" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/sdrwebview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should solve the problem

[Android AdMob Position top of screen not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105894/android-admob-position-top-of-screen-not-working/5188181#5188181)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

on the Webview