# can't see ads (admob) on my android app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm trying to add some advertising to my app with admob, by I'm already using admob sdk 4.1.1. 
I saw a few posts here but they refer older versions.

I only used xml configurations didn't change anything on java side. my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> 
         <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"                          
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"                          
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"                          
                  ads:adUnitId="--myUnitId--"                        
                  ads:adSize="BANNER"                          
                  ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"  
                 /> 

            </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I can't see any ads in my app. I see some requests on admob dashboard, but zero impressions. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is? Am I missing some code?

Thanks in advance,

João

Answer (score 0):

Look into logcat - admob usually logs attempts to retrieve new ad.  This  is pretty comon that no ad is available or there is  some connectivity problem

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying in my physic device, not the emulator, how can i see the logcat in the device?

Comment: there is a tool called ddms, there is adb in SDK and if all else fails there are apps which will send logcat output to you via email

Comment: thanks, I downloaded an app (aLogCat), that allowed me to send the log by email, and analyze my requests

Answer (score 0):

If you see requests on your AdMob dashboard, then you are likely getting the issue of "Ad Request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of inventory."  AdMob doesn't always have an ad to show, and it typically takes multiple requests and some time for new apps to start receiving real ads.

Comment: yes, you're right, with the tool sugested by konstantin I see the error/info you mentioned. Yesterday I saw a few impressions, but is about 10% of the requests, isn't this weird? Will this percentage  improve?

Comment: Have you enabled Google AdSense backfill?  If you click "Manage Settings" on your site/app and click on the "App Settings" tab, there will be an option to turn this on.  It is off by default.  Turning this on will significantly improve fill rate.  Also check to make sure you don't have filters turned off that you want to have turned on.  Ads are slow to start coming in, but long term with AdSense enabled you should get way way more than 10% fill rate.

Answer (score 0):

Ads might be hiding behind or you might have pushed it out of the screen. You may use Relative Layout if you want the ads to be always displayed at the bottom.

Here is the code,

[Android AdMob Position top of screen not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105894/android-admob-position-top-of-screen-not-working/5188181#5188181)

Comment: I'll check your code, but I guess that is not the problem because to test I removed every other views. thanks

Comment: Check this out http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addadview